# SQL Server SSIS Custom assembly with licence key

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that runs fine from Visual Studio but doesn’t work on the server.

Executing under my security context produces the same results as a proxy account.

It's running a custom assembly

- The server is running SQL Server 2016
- The server has the shared components installed on a different drive (d:)
- There is a script task that needs a licence key
- Runs fine locally using Visual Studio 2013 (I edited 64 & 32 bit versions of DtsDebugHost.exe.config)
- On the server I installed three dll's to the GAC & placed a copy in Program Files and (x86) \Microsoft SQL Server\130\SDK\Assemblies\

  1. a.dll          - MSIL
  2. b.dll          - MSIL
  3. kernelx86.dll  - X86

One of them wouldn't install to the GAC until I edited the GACUTILs config and put the below line in.

Then I edited the config files for running SSIS packages;

```
1. DTExec.exe.config - Command line execution  
2. DtsDebugHost.exe.config - Visual Studio debugging  
3. DtsHost.exe.config - SQL Server agent
```

Either one of the DLLs isn't being used or the licence key still isn't being picked up.

Any suggestions are appreciated,

Dan

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Quick update all, I've tracked this down as DCOM permissions.
Everytime permissions are given on an Application ID though it errors and Event Viewer shows a different Application ID